# Avoid Notes while playing chords over chords

Tags: harmony

im just wondering how people work with avoid notes when playing chords over a drone chord.
If you watch this video of this song i really enjoy I noticed this composer uses a bunch of avoid notes over a chord and not just passing notes or notes that are not important but structure notes

do some people just ignore avoid notes?

so to be more detailed for example he has the dominant chord or mixolydian and then he's using a 4th note of the mixolydian scale as a structural note.

for more on avoid notes [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoid_note#:~:text=In%20jazz%20theory%2C%20an%20avoid,chord%2C%20and%20thus%20very%20harsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoid_note#:%7E:text=In%20jazz%20theory%2C%20an%20avoid,chord%2C%20and%20thus%20very%20harsh).

Comment: What are "avoid notes"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoid_note#:~:text=In%20jazz%20theory%2C%20an%20avoid,chord%2C%20and%20thus%20very%20harsh.  i thought everyone knew about these.. i read it in a jazz book

Comment: In the timed spot the video is set to, there is no dominant chord. Did you intend to set the video to a different place?

Comment: However, the answer to your question is, yes, sometimes people ignore avoid notes. Avoid notes are just suggestions given to beginning jazz players.

Comment: sorry i didnt mean to put the video at a specific time.  thanks for the answer!

Comment: Could you then point at what time, with which chord do you believe the avoid note is used?

Comment: To me it seems weird to apply Jazz theory to such pieces that are obviously classical. Having a fourth in a dominant chord is a very standard suspension of the leading tone.

Comment: I like the idea that "avoid notes" are the ones that are out of tune or broken on your piano. :)

Comment: Can you please edit in the section you are focused on so folks don't have to go through the entire video and guess. I have popped this on hold until fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good answer, just an answer.

Quote from Jazz Piano Book by Mark Levine:

> “Avoid” note is not a very good term, because it implies that you
> shouldn’t play it. A better name would be “handle with care” note.
> Unfortunately, that’s not as catchy, so I’ll (reluctantly) stick with
> “avoid” note.

Having to teach "avoid notes" is bizarre, as if they were teaching deaf people how to play.  If there's a note you don't like for whatever you're trying to do, don't use it. It is possible to spoil a desired musical effect with ANY note, if played the wrong way. I guess the point is just to tell the students "pay special attention to this note and the effect it has in various situations". Not "avoid" the note. You don't avoid making food, because it's possible to get burns. Luckily nobody decided to call the kitchen an "AVOID ROOM".

So forget about "avoid notes". Practice more and develop a sense for hearing and feeling what you're doing. Play more, consume less theory talk. One hour of theory or Youtube is allowed for every ten hours of actual practicing. And choose better theory books to read. ;)

Speaking of which, there are some regular users here who would probably label the Levine books as "avoid books"... But if you have a substantial musical practice and take theory talk as what it is - people talking about doing musical things - you can put things into perspective. There is no single one-and-only correct way of practicing music, and there is no single one-and-only correct way of talking about practicing music either. Practice more, consume less theory-tainment, that's my recipe.

Comment: Aka, in the popular misquote of Duke Ellington, "If it sounds good it is good." And vice versa.

Comment: And Duke Ellington did not use the "avoid note" concept.

Answer (score 0):

"Avoid note" is a term from academic jazz. It's a short hand way to help beginners avoid certain dissonances.

IMO one of the problems with the "avoid note" concept is it gives beginners the impression there a certain tones you *aren't allowed to use*. This is very simply wrong. Additionally the "avoid note" concept seems to result in many students also *avoiding* learning basic harmony concepts, namely the difference between harmonic and non-harmonic tones.

Additionally, you should be cautious about applying a theory concept, like "avoid note", outside of the music style the theory describes. So, outside of playing academic style jazz, I think you should avoid using the "avoid tone" concept. The music in your example isn't any kind of jazz.

Requesting analysis is off topic, so I didn't look too deeply at the example, however I don't really see what I expected for "playing chords over chords." I expected something with polytonality or poly chords like *Debussy - Étude 10 pour les sonorités opposées* or *Milhuad - Saudades do Brazil.* You example looks like extended chords with a melody on top. The style is modern, but maybe not polychords.

When you get into a modern harmonic styles that uses extended and/or chromatic harmonies you need to grapple with the concept of what is dissonance? Simple case in point would be a full thirteenth chord, which if complete, contains all tones of the scale/key. In that case all tones are chord tones, therefore no tone of the scale/key is dissonant to the chord. That doesn't necessarily mean all bets are off regarding dissonance - like in twelve tone music - but it does mean that a different approach to dissonance, something beyond chord tone/non-chord tone is needed.

Importantly there *is no textbook analysis approach* for this kind of modern harmony. Actually, in many harmony textbooks, all the detail of "rules" is for the common practice era music, while sometimes the end of the textbook as a brief overview of modernism. Close/open chord voicing could be a factor, diatonic vs. non-diatonic could be a factor, handling of inner vs. outer voices could be a factor, etc. etc. Or you could simple dump that the piece has any meaningful concept of dissonance.

In a way assessing dissonance is a kind of "value judgement." Perhaps the first thing to do is describe what the piece *actually does* with out labeling dissonance, without getting bogged down in the value judgement. If, for example, the piece became chromatic and used augmented/diminished intervals mostly at some climax point, then you have made a meaningful harmonic and structural analysis of the piece. You could do such an analysis without necessarily labeling dissonance.

Comment: "academic style jazz" LOL That sounds like an awesome genre, can you give some example artists or records to listen to? It's a good answer, too bad the question got closed already. +1 I would have liked to hear more answers about why "avoid note" is a harmful concept. I think most people with any experience would agree it's a dumb idea.

Comment: Adam Neely calls it "Berklee Jazz." Probably any fusion jazz style. I think of it more as what's not academic jazz: Ellington, Davis, Monk, etc. etc. Reminds me of a great quote I heard somewhere: Thelonious Monk would not be able to win the the Thelonious Monk Institute Jazz Competition.

Comment: But, really, the point about "academic" was about the teaching, not a genre or players.

Comment: Isn't it widely understood that "avoid note" is a shorthand for a more complex topic? Is anyone teaching, on academic level, that you should literally _avoid_ some notes?

Comment: Apparently that is not widely understood, because the OP's sense of a prohibition seems pretty common. The misunderstanding isn't surprising. If you label something "avoid", and don't explain why (as all the sources I've seen fail to do), then if you don't understand why, the natural thing is to avoid "avoid notes" entirely.

Comment: Why the sensitivity anytime I critique the shortcomings of jazz theory? When I point out problems of chord/scale system, or avoid tones, etc. there is always some anonymous downvoter. Yet, when I critique something like the functional chord flow charts in Kostka/Payne I don't have to deal with hurt feelings and downvoters.

Comment: At this stage it's unclear what OP actually meant, which is the reason the question is closed.

Comment: I don't get the downvote either. My answer got only upvotes, even though I tried to be even harsher in saying that the avoid note concept is dumb. This answer nicely points out that avoiding certain notes results in avoiding _learning_. Such a "don't touch" mentality may be needed for avoiding life-threatening accidents. But in music, I cannot see the benefit, unless the students are determined to be pathological cases who are unable to develop a sensitivity to hearing what they're doing. But even for those cases, they should first TRY and see how far they get, before giving up.

Comment: In actuality dissonant non-chord tones - so called "avoid tones" - are often the _defining_ feature of memorable and expressive melodies. Ex. the song _Moon River_, or Viennese "sighing" appoggiaturas. Avoiding those notes makes for bland, generic melody. You don't avoid them, you _exploit_ them.